# How to display labels on top of lines?

Tags: pine-script

At the moment, my hlines are showing up over the labels.
I would like my labels to be on top of the lines. 
[image]

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the plotshape()-function or the label.new()-function to plot your labels?

In case of plotshape() you can set the location parameter to location.absolute and the series parameter to something like "condition ? position : na", where position would be your y-value and greater than your hline value.

In case of label.new() simply change the y value where you want the label to appear.

Comment: Hello @Paaax! Thanks for your answer. 
Yes, I use the Plotshape() function with location.absolute.
Quite newbie to pine-script, so I'm not sure on how to write the series parameter you're describing.

Comment: Basically just copy and paste the "condition ? position : na" part that I have posted as the first argument of the plotshape()-function.

You will have to define your condition, which is your current "series" parameter and the position should be a value for the y Axis.


`code
float position = 1230.1 // here you have to set your y Axis value
plotshape(condition ? position : na, location=location.absolute,....)`